# Tensorflow ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 41), found shape=(128, 66)

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I keep on getting this error related to input shape. Thanks in advance!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from pandas import read_csv
import numpy as np

dataset = read_csv('training.csv')
GRU=tf.keras.layers.GRU

tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(
    num_words=70000,
    lower=True,
    oov_token=''
)

update_dict = {0:'üzüntü', 1:'neşe', 2:'aşk', 3:'öfke', 4:'korku', 5:'şaşırma'}

dataset['mappedLabel'] = dataset['label'].map(update_dict)

dataset.sample()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

dataset['label'].value_counts()

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(
    dataset['text'],dataset['label'],
    test_size = 0.20,
    random_state = 5,
    stratify=dataset['label']
)

tokenizer.fit_on_texts(x_train)

x_train_transformed =tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_train)

x_test_transformed = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(x_test)

x_train_padded = tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(
    x_train_transformed,
    maxlen=66
)

x_test_padded = tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(
    x_test_transformed,
    maxlen=66
)

num_tokens=[
    len(tokens) for tokens in x_train_transformed+x_test_transformed
]
num_tokens = np.array(num_tokens)

max_tokens = np.mean(
    num_tokens+2*np.std(num_tokens)
)
max_tokens = int(max_tokens)

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(len(word_index),65,input_length=max_tokens))

model.add(GRU(
    32,
    use_bias=False,
    dropout=0.1,
    recurrent_dropout=0.1,
    return_sequences=True  
))
model.add(GRU(
    16,
    use_bias=True,
    dropout=0.1,
    recurrent_dropout=0.2,
    return_sequences=True 
))
model.add(GRU(
    8,
    use_bias=True,
))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(6,activation="softmax"))

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(
        learning_rate=0.001,
        beta_1=0.9,
        beta_2=0.999,
        epsilon=1e-8,
    ),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(
    x_train_padded,
    y_train,
    batch_size=128,
    validation_split=0.2,
    epochs=10
)
```

Error :

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 41), found shape=(128, 66)
> I think it's a bug with the model.fit() part.
> I am using Jupyter notebook.

This program was supposed to be trained to do sentiment analysis but it gave this error.